# Screen-less Laptop

Tags: windows-7, hp-pavilion

So, I took the screen off my old laptop (HP Pavilion dv6). The idea was to use it as a media center for my living room. Well, I have it hooked up to my TV, via hdmi. The problem is that I can't see anything on the screen, until I log on to Windows. But because I'm such a smart man, I don't have a laptop screen or extra monitor to see what I'm logging on to. Is there a way to use anything as a screen? Maybe a phone or tablet? A different cord? Or did I just make my laptop useless?

Comment: Can you temporarily reattach the original screen?  You probably just need to have both the laptop screen and the TV attached, then change which one is listed as primary, then you can remove the laptop screen again.

Comment: @techturtle I tried last night, but I couldn't fit the cable to the screen. I'll try it again though. It could've been because of the terrible lighting I had.

Comment: Alright, I have the screen working again. But I always used my fingerprint to log on. Is there a way in the BIOS to set it up to have my TV as the primary screen?

Comment: I don't know a way in the BIOS.  With both attached, you should be able to set them to "mirror" instead of "extend" in the display properties.  This should make it so both the laptop screen and the TV display the same info, including the login prompts.  Then you would be safe to remove the laptop screen again.